# URLRetrieve Error Handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I have the following code that grabs images using urlretrieve working..... too a point.

```
def Opt3():
    global conn
    curs = conn.cursor()
    results = curs.execute("SELECT stock_code FROM COMPANY")

    for row in results:
    #for image_name in list_of_image_names:
        page = requests.get('url?prodid=' +     row[0])
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        pic = tree.xpath('//*[@id="bigImg0"]')

        #print pic[0].attrib['src']
        print 'URL'+pic[0].attrib['src']
        try:
            urllib.urlretrieve('URL'+pic[0].attrib['src'],'images\\'+row[0]+'.jpg')
        except:
            pass
```

I am reading a CSV to input the image names.  It works except when it hits an error/corrupt url (where there is no image I think).  I was wondering if I could simply skip any corrupt urls and get the code to continue grabbing images? Thanks

Comment: You have spelled `except` incorrectly

Comment: Thanks Padraic, it is actually correct in my code locally

Comment: so you want to continue if requests.get fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `try/except` and `continue` if it fails

```
try:
    page = requests.get('url?prodid=' +     row[0])
except Exception,e:
    print e
    continue # continue to next row
```

Comment: Both the OP and you should really use specific exceptions, this isn't Pokemon (you *don't* want to catch them all).

Comment: In this case, catch [`requests.exceptions.RequestException`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#exceptions). You probably should call [`page.raise_for_status()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) to turn non-200 responses into exceptions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, where would I call `page.raise_for_status()`?

Comment: Inside the `try` suite. The `HTTPError` raised is a subclass of `RequestException`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, what should the output be?

Comment: There is no output. The method raises an exception if the HTTP response indicated there was a problem (so a 4xx or 5xx response code was given).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I still don't follow. Will  catching `requests.exceptions.RequestException` not suffice, what exactly does using `page.raise_for_status()` accomplish?

Comment: It handles all URLs that did **not** raise an exception. A 404 Not Found response from the server is not automatically an exception, but the rest of the loop needs to be skipped nonetheless. Either you test for `page.status_code` manually, or you use `raise_for_status()` and treat it like any other exception that the `requests.get()` call could have raised (like a connection error or a timeout).

Comment: I ended up just moving the 'Print' into the 'Try' and it worked.... Thanks for answering guys

Comment: will an `assert page.status_code == 200` in the block  work or just use an if check before the continue?

Answer (score 3):

urllib has a very bad support for error catching. urllib2 is a much better choice. The `urlretrieve` equivalent in urllib2 is:

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen(im_url)
with open(sav_name, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(resp.read())
```

And the errors to catch are:

```
urllib2.URLError, urllib2.HTTPError, httplib.HTTPException
```

And you can also catch `socket.error` in case that the network is down.
Simply using `except Exception` is a very stupid idea. It'll catch every error in the above block even your typos.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of pass why don't you try continue when an error occurs.

```
try:
    urllib.urlretrieve('URL'+pic[0].attrib['src'],'images\\'+row[0]+'.jpg')

except Exception e:
    continue
```